# Is there a faster way to check for the largest value(int or double) in an array?

Tags: java, shortcut

The following code compiles just fine, I just wanted to know if I could do everything in a much shorter form. Pardon me if i'm overlooking something really simple. Also I used `a.length-a.length` instead of 0 because I'm doing this to show that I know WHY this or that for APCSA.

```
public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //Goal is to make a quick program that finds the largest value in an array.
    {
        int a[] = new int[]{2,2,3,4,5,6,6,2,8}; //Arbitrary Values
        int lnum = 0;
        for(int i = a.length-a.length; i < a.length; i++){ // Used a.length-a.length instead of 0
            if (i==a.length-a.length){ // Used a.length-a.length instead of 0
                lnum = a[i];
            }
            else if(a[i]>lnum && a[i]>a[i-1]){
                lnum = a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can sort the array using Array.sort()

Comment: if you really want to use a for loop you can set `lnum = Math.max(lnum,a[i])` rather than the if

Comment: Why `a.length-a.length` instead of 0? That's an unnecessary und unexpected calculation.

Comment: Always consider test cases as any examiner might try: your code will not work for `a=int[]{-2}` or null or empty array `int[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> if I could do everything in a much shorter form

Shorter? Let a stream do the work. It’s a one-liner.

```
Arrays
.stream( new int[] { 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 6 , 2 , 8 } )
.max()
.getAsInt()
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com.](https://ideone.com/E3ZqWv)

> 8

## Details

Call [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)) to make a stream of an array’s elements, an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). Call [`IntStream#max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max()) to get the biggest value.

The result is an [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html), optional because if your array were empty there would be no `int` value to return. The `OptionalInt#getAsInt` method returns a value if present, otherwise throws [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).

```java
int[] a = new int[] { 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 6 , 2 , 8 }; 
int max = Arrays.stream( a ).max().getAsInt();
```

> 8